# Ionic - Cannot load empty config.xml file and ionic integrations enable cordova --add doesn't work

Tags: typescript, cordova, visual-studio-code, ionic-framework, npm

I am getting a Cannot load empty config.xml file when I try to run ionic cordova in Visual Studio Code. And

```
ionic integrations enable cordova --add
```

doesn't work. How can I fix this problem ?

I tried

```
ionic integrations enable cordova --add
```

several times and it doesn't work.

After that I delete and re-install the platform with `cordova add platform android` and I got the Error `Cannot load Cordova config.INVALID_PACKAGE_JSON`. To get rid of the invalid Json I used `npm init` and now, after running `ionic cordova build` I get the error

```
Cannot run sass task: missing in gulpfile.js
```

the **package.json**

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "test",
    "homepage": "http://test.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
        "ng-swagger-gen": "ng-swagger-gen -c swagger-gen/ng-swagger-gen.conf.json"
    },
"devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.3",
        "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "file:plugin-src/com-sarriaroman-photoviewer",
        "cordova-android": "^11.0.0",
        "cordova-ios": "^6.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-badge": "file:plugin-src/cordova-plugin-badge",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^6.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^7.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "file:plugin-src/cordova-plugin-local-notification",
        "cordova-plugin-media": "file:plugin-src/cordova-plugin-media",
        "cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller": "^2.0.0",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.0",
        "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^6.0.4",
        "ng-swagger-gen": "0.11.4",
        "typescript": "2.6.2"
    },

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to hear that. Let's start from the beginning and work upwards from that. We'll start with your first problem you mentioned in your post,

The first error indicates that the Cordova config in your project is either broken or empty. To fix this, you can try regenerating the `config.xml` file by running the following command:

```bash
ionic integrations enable cordova --add
```

Now regarding your second issue,

If this command does not work (as you mentioned), you can try manually creating a new `config.xml` file in the root directory of your project and populating it with the appropriate values. Here is an example `config.xml` file that you can use as a starting point (simplified version of [a gist](https://gist.github.com/duluca/64b6caaae4a7cd77e7b7e32e67bf7098)):

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="your.app.id" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>Your App Name</name>
  <description>Your app description.</description>
  <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com">Your Name</author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Make sure to replace the `id`, `name`, `description`, and `author` fields with your own values before running your app.

Now, regarding the `Cannot run sass task: missing in gulpfile.js` error you mentioned, it may indicate that your project is missing the Gulp build tool. You can try installing Gulp by running the following command:

```bash
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

After that, make sure you have a `gulpfile.js` file in your root project directory. Here is an example `gulpfile.js` that you can use as a starting point and build off of:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

This gulpfile defines a sass task that compiles your scss files and outputs the resulting CSS to the `www/css` directory. It also defines `sass:watch` task that watches for changes to your scss files and automatically recompiles them.

Once you have done all of this, try running `ionic cordova build` again and see if the error persists.

If it still persists, it may be time to recreate your project and retry the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

To install cordova use:

> npm install -g cordova

To add corova in your project:

> ionic integrations enable cordova --add

Comment: Run "ionic cordova prepare" commond it will add confix.xml

Comment: I still get the same output.

Comment: Remove platform and add it again.

Comment: I removed the platform. Still the same output, Should I share the config.xml and the package.json ?

Comment: "ionic cordova resources"
This command will create a new config.xml file with default settings.

Comment: Have you added platform again?

Comment: same output for "ionic cordova resources". Maybe I should delete the config.xml ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251930/discussion-between-satish-birhade-and-nzl81372).

Comment: I add the platform again with "cordova platform add android". After that i tried again "ionic cordova build" and I get this error: "Cannot load Cordova config. INVALID_PACKAGE_JSON"

Comment: not add integration

ionic integrations enable cordova --add